# EF audit in place code duplication

Tags: entity-framework

I have some code that is very similar and would like to reduce the amount of duplication.

The following two methods are similar in every respect except for the DbSet<> being operated upon. One operating on PPDs and the other operating on ChestXRays.

How can I remove the amount of duplication as I've got many more DbSet<> I need to act upon similarly.

```
    public CommandResult CreditPpdService(GenericCreditDto vm)
    {
        var insertModified = _hlthOidContext.PPDs
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.PPDId == vm.TheServiceId);
        if (insertModified != null)
        {
            var flagOriginalAsDeleted = _hlthOidContext.PPDs
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.PPDId == vm.TheServiceId);
            if (flagOriginalAsDeleted != null)
            {
                flagOriginalAsDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
            }
            _hlthOidContext.PPDs.Add(insertModified);
            _hlthOidContext.Entry(insertModified).CurrentValues.SetValues(vm);
            _hlthOidContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        var results = new CommandResult();
        return results;
    }
```

and the other method

```
        public CommandResult CreditChestXRayService(GenericCreditDto vm)
    {
        var insertModified = _hlthOidContext.ChestXRays
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChestXRayId == vm.TheServiceId);
        if (insertModified != null)
        {
            var flagOriginalAsDeleted = _hlthOidContext.ChestXRays
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChestXRayId == vm.TheServiceId);
            if (flagOriginalAsDeleted != null)
            {
                flagOriginalAsDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
            }
            _hlthOidContext.ChestXRays.Add(insertModified);
            _hlthOidContext.Entry(insertModified).CurrentValues.SetValues(vm);
            _hlthOidContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        var results = new CommandResult();
        return results;
    }
```

where _hlthOidContext is

```
public partial class HLTH_OIDContext : DbContext
{
    static HLTH_OIDContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<HLTH_OIDContext>(null);
    }

    public HLTH_OIDContext()
        : base("Name=HLTH_OIDContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    ...
    public DbSet<ChestXRay> ChestXRays { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PPD> PPDs { get; set; }
    ...
```

some more information

```
    public interface ISoftDelete
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }         
}

public partial class ChestXRay : ISoftDelete { }
...
public partial class PPD : ISoftDelete { }
```

Comment: In general - try to follow S.O.L.I.D principles by using Design Patterns. In particular example use Generic method. Question: is _hlthOidContext DbSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea, which I'll show as a series of refactorings over your current code. It would be easier if the "Id" property was the same for each type (`ChestXRayId`, `PPDId` etc), because you could extract the `Id` into a common interface as well.

First refactor your DbSets and `FirstOrDefault` predicate into variables:

```
public CommandResult CreditChestXRayService(GenericCreditDto vm)
{
    DbSet<ChestXRays> dbSet = _hlthOidContext.ChestXRays;
    Expression<Func<ChestXRays, bool>> predicate = c => c.ChestXRayId == vm.TheServiceId;

    var insertModified = dbSet
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    if (insertModified != null)
    {
        var flagOriginalAsDeleted = dbSet
            .FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (flagOriginalAsDeleted != null)
        {
            flagOriginalAsDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
        }
        dbSet.Add(insertModified);
        _hlthOidContext.Entry(insertModified).CurrentValues.SetValues(vm);
        _hlthOidContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    var results = new CommandResult();
    return results;
}
```

Then extract a generic type argument and parameterize these variables.

You'll need an interface for the `IsDeleted` property, and to restrict your generic types to this interface (from the comments, looks like this is implemented via `ISoftDelete`).

```
private CommandResult CreditService<T>(GenericCreditDto vm, DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
    where T : class, ISoftDelete
{
    var insertModified = dbSet
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    if (insertModified != null)
    {
        var flagOriginalAsDeleted = dbSet
            .FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (flagOriginalAsDeleted != null)
        {
            flagOriginalAsDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
        }
        dbSet.Add(insertModified);
        _hlthOidContext.Entry(insertModified).CurrentValues.SetValues(vm);
        _hlthOidContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    var results = new CommandResult();
    return results;
}
```

Call this generic method using any of your specific types:

```
public CommandResult CreditChestXRayService(GenericCreditDto vm)
{
    return CreditService(vm, _hlthOidContext.ChestXRays, c => c.ChestXRayId == vm.TheServiceId);
}

public CommandResult CreditPpdService(GenericCreditDto vm)
{
    return CreditService(vm, _hlthOidContext.PPDs, c => c.PPDId == vm.TheServiceId);
}
```

Comment: had to change a dbSet parameter to ref.
But am getting a cannot resolve symbol on flagOriginalAsDeleted.IsDeleted. our implementation of IsDeleted is thru  public interface ISoftDelete
    {
        bool IsDeleted { get; set; }         
    }
    public partial class PPD : ISoftDelete { }
    public partial class ChestXRay : ISoftDelete { }

Comment: I updated the type constraint to use the existing `ISoftDelete` interface.  I'm not sure why you'd need the dbSet parameter to be passed by ref; it's a reference type, so unless you're changing the caller's instance of the dbSet, you should be okay without passing by ref.

Comment: got it. needed to do this:         private CommandResult CreditService<T>(GenericCreditDto vm, ref DbSet<T> dbSet, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class, ISoftDelete

Comment: @AlanMIERS Glad it works. I just noticed that you should also change the predicate argument type to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` so that the predicate can be used as a linq expression and transformed as part of the query.  Otherwise you'll end up using the `Enumerable` `FirstOrDefault` method which isn't handled by the dbSet queryable provider.